# Converting an array of string to array of int in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a vardump result for some array like this:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(1) "0" }
```

Now I want the result to like this:

```
array(2) { [0]=> int(2) [1]=> int(0) }
```

is any idea for a simple answer..?

Comment: Im guessing its because your variables are strings, and need to be integers.
You might want to look into variable types, its a simple thing to solve  really. Also, no need to shout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) i.e.

```
$array = array_map(function($n) { return (int)$i; }, $array);
```

Answer (score 1):

So Ed-Heal already sent a really good answer, and more efficient, but I will post one with a for loop just to explain the process:

```
$stringArray = array("2","5"); // We set up the string array

var_dump($stringArray);

// We loop through the array:
for ($i = 0; $i<sizeof($stringArray); $i++) {
    // We set the value at the index $i to an integer.
    $stringArray[$i] = intval($stringArray[$i]);
}

var_dump($stringArray);
```

The output of the code above would be as follows

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(1) "5" }
array(2) { [0]=> int(2) [1]=> int(5) }
```

So what does this code do?
Well we loop through the array, we grab every value and change it with a integer with the function intval().

Oh and please, don't capsize your question's title.